# Scrollable fails when collection has over 11 containers

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

why jquerytools scrollable fails when collection has over 11 containers?

Example http://jsfiddle.net/bDUTy/
scroll to 12 frame and further

Comment: It works fine with any newer release of jQuery (newer than 1.4.4 that is).  Release 1.4.4 is pretty old, and many improvements and fixes have been made since then.